# Delete/Modify data from MySql at set interval

Tags: mysql, sql, time, intervals

I don't have any code, or any idea how to do this. But what i'd like to do is set modifications to happen at a set time every week, like for all users "SET user_number = 0" every Friday at 5pm. or even something that will "DELETE * FROM user_table" every Friday at 5 pm. sorry if this is a newb question, I've looked around SO and google and can't find anything.

Comment: Well there is a CRON Job, or a MYSQL Event that you could look up

Comment: @RiggsFolly i'll look those up! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL events.

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 WEEK
    STARTS '2020-05-22 17:00:00' 
  DO
    # Your query
```

Comment: thank you. I didn't even know this was a thing untill now